# C++ Game Sound Effects

Tags: c++, wav

Is it possible to load in a `wav` file and play in during a game that's been written in C++ without the use of third party libraries?

I mean, is there a small function that can handle this?

Some third party libraries seem to use huge amounts of code to do it. I found the same thing when loading images. Some libraries use so much code when sometimes it's possible to do the same amount of work in a small function... I just wondered if it was the same for audio files?

If not, what are the best/most basic Audio libraries that you guys know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ by itself has no concept of multimedia.  Unless you write your own multimedia code, then you have to use libraries or platform-specific APIs for working with multimedia content and output.  For instance, on Windows, the simpliest option is the Win32 API `PlaySound()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your questions one at a time.

**Is it possible to LOAD a wav file without using 3rd party lib.?**

Yes, certainly it is. A quick search brings up: http://home.foni.net/~wkurz/dynaplot/applicationnotes/loadwav.htm

**Is it possible to PLAY a wav file without using 3rd party lib.?**

Again, yes it is possible. Provided you are willing to write drivers for all possible combinations of hardware and OSs you are targetting.

Allow me to suggest a solution: use some opensource lib. There are many excellent ones out there. I use following for my (non-gaming apps)

- Loading wav: [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)
- Playing wav: [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)

hope that helps